# Chrome extension modal dialog or other solution to notify users?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I have created a chrome extension when clicked opens a popup for users to save curent tab as screenshot.

Screenshot:

[image]

The probelm is that when *I go to some other tab and come back to tab where extension window was open*, the window is no more there (though it still performs screenshot creation). Because of this one is not able to know whether extension actually created the screenshot and even the desktop notification doesn't show in this case since window went invisile after switching to other tabs and coming back.

Is there anyway to make this popup modal or some other solution so that users are able to know that screenshot was created even if they go to other tabs and come back to tab where extension was used ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you are looking for some modal Window code you can take this as a reference and customize to your requirements.

## Output

[Click For Larger Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2vj7.png)

[image]

The idea is to engross a processing text mimic of a modal dialog.

## Demonstration

#### manifest.json

Added a simple modal window through content script with a `gif` image.

```
{
    "name": "Add Model Window",
    "description": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14423923/chrome-extension-modal-dialog-or-other-solution-to-notify-users",
    "version": "1",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "<all_urls>"
            ],
            "js": [
                "modal.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        "spinner_progress.gif"
    ]
}
```

#### modal.js

### Target HTML to be formed

The idea is to paste an `<iframe>` on the page and add a cosmetic panel for customized text.

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.5; z-index: 2000; height: 1083px; width: 100%;">
    <iframe style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; width: 350px; border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 2001; overflow: auto; text-align: center; top: 149px; left: 497px;">
    <div>
        <div style="text-align:center"><span><strong>Processing...  Please Wait.</strong></span>

            <br>
            <br>
            <img src="/img/spinner_progress.gif">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### Code for HTML Using Basic DOM Operations.

```
wrapperDiv = document.createElement("div");
wrapperDiv.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.5; z-index: 2000; height: 1083px; width: 100%;");

iframeElement = document.createElement("iframe");
iframeElement.setAttribute("style","width: 100%; height: 100%;");

wrapperDiv.appendChild(iframeElement);

modalDialogParentDiv = document.createElement("div");
modalDialogParentDiv.setAttribute("style","position: absolute; width: 350px; border: 1px solid rgb(51, 102, 153); padding: 10px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); z-index: 2001; overflow: auto; text-align: center; top: 149px; left: 497px;");

modalDialogSiblingDiv = document.createElement("div");

modalDialogTextDiv = document.createElement("div"); 
modalDialogTextDiv.setAttribute("style" , "text-align:center");

modalDialogTextSpan = document.createElement("span"); 
modalDialogText = document.createElement("strong"); 
modalDialogText.innerHTML = "Processing...  Please Wait.";

breakElement = document.createElement("br"); 
imageElement = document.createElement("img"); 
imageElement.src = chrome.extension.getURL("spinner_progress.gif");

modalDialogTextSpan.appendChild(modalDialogText);
modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(modalDialogTextSpan);
modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement);
modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(breakElement);
modalDialogTextDiv.appendChild(imageElement);

modalDialogSiblingDiv.appendChild(modalDialogTextDiv);
modalDialogParentDiv.appendChild(modalDialogSiblingDiv);

document.body.appendChild(wrapperDiv);
document.body.appendChild(modalDialogParentDiv);
```

Answer (score 3):

Popups in Chrome closes by design when you click outside the popup area (well, not only, due to an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=163851) - but it's OT). There's no way to keep it opened.

Alternative ways could be:

- to inform the user via desktop notification
- open another tab (once the extension has done with its job) with a successful message
- shows an alert
- shows a modal on the screenshot-ed page.
- [experimental infobars](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental.infobars.html)

Probably there are other ways of course, but I guess these are the most usable.

Comment: Desktop notification doesn't show if popup goes invisible like in my case. It shows if popup is visible. How to show modal by the way ?

Comment: Desktop notifications aren't related to popups, so they can be shown even if popup isn't visible. Your problem probably is that you do all the work directly form the popup so, if your popup closes, all your extension's logic stop to work. To solve you should move the logic from the popup code to the background code and from there call the desktop notification once the screenshotting has done. Modals can be obtained using content script on the screenshotted page and simple HTML+CSS+JS.

Comment: Moved code to background page and even then if window is invisible notification doesnt show up, shows only when window is visible :(

Comment: It's a little bit hard to solve without code to see. Basically, once you set your permissions in manifest, what you have to do is to call the screenshot function inside your background code (or you can use messaging to achieve the same result) from your popup code, which will start to capture the active page, and when finished will call the callback function that will show the desktop notification.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I already +1 you. @Sudarshan's answers does the job. Thanks you too :)